# How to save a multi-culture versioned form submit using Sitecore Webforms for Marketers (WFFM)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

The most of you probably know that in Belgium are spoken multi languages. I must integrate a handling for these multi languages in the save action of a webform. The languages are bordered to Dutch and French.

For handling forms I have installed Sitecore Webforms For Marketers (WFFM). With WFFM I have created 2 language versions of the form. I have defined a custom save action to store the form values in the Master database (as an item).

What is the problem? The problem is that an item in the Master database is not stored on the correct language. The cause is that WFFM for both language versions of the form using the same custom save action. Is there anyone who knows how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Comment: Hi Jordy. Can you add to your question the code in the SaveAction that creates the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your save action you need to somehow get the front end users context language first. Then when you access your storage repository folder in the master DB, get that master DB item in the language of the front end user (Dutch or French):

```
Master.GetItem(storagePath, ctxLanguage)
```

Now when you create the record in the master DB it will be in the language of the front end user.

Comment: Sure, but how do I get the language of the front end user in the backend?

Comment: Provide a snippet of your save action in the question. There is likely a way to access the context.

Comment: I think there is not. I'm using a webservice to store the values in a Sitecore item. The webservice url is static. So you cannot get the right context.

Comment: If you place the webservice in /sitecore modules folder, it will have the language context. Look here: http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/access-sitecore-data-with-wcf/

Comment: Jordy, the save action is what matters. Please show us the code for your custom save action.

Comment: Do I understand this right? You have a language versioned form on a standard language versioned Sitecore site. The form submits to the WFFM module, where it triggers a custom save action. The custom save action calls a webservice, which creates/updates an item in the master database. The webservice doesn't run in a language context, and doesn't accept language as a parameter. What's important here is working out where you lose language, and where you need it. Save actions, for instance, include a "localized parameters" field. We use this e.g. to specify local from addresses in email responses.

Answer (score 0):

Jordy,

The easiest way to go about this, is to remove the "shared" checkbox in the form template on the save actions field.
That way, you can specify a specific action for every language.

I might add, you HAVE to specify actions in every language if you do this, don't forget!

You can find the form template under templates/web forms for marketers/form

Hope this helps!

Erwin

Comment: This seems like the best answer. However, it doesn't work for me. The field is now marked as [unversioned] but not shared, but somehow changes I make in one language end up in the other languages as well.